# UWP Listview with itemswrapgrid setting width based on items content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an Listview with togglebuttons in datatemplate in UWP. I have configured the listview as itemwrapgrid. I am trying to assign diffrent width for items based on toggle buttons content length. Can anyone help me to do this.

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstVw1" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></ItemsWrapGrid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding ItemText}" Click="ToggleButton_Click">
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />

                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <ContentPresenter Padding="5"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>

                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
```

The above xaml gives equaly sized toggle buttons in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a custom wrap panel for the above.

[Reference](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/ui/wrap-grid-with-variable-sized-items/)

Answer (score 3):

I would use the WrapPanel from the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit). You can download the nuget package and then change your ItemsPanel of your ListView to be a WrapPanel

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <wrapPanel:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Note that the WrapPanel was accidentally put into the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Controls.WrapPanel` namespace, so you'll need to declare the wrapPanel namespace in your XAML

```
xmlns:wrapPanel="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Controls.WrapPanel"
```

Comment: Note that the control will move to the proper `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Controls` namespace at version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly like that by default - `ItemTemplate` will expand to fit the content. You might need to use `ItemsStackPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

What you did wrong is this line, you should remove it:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
```